# Are csrf-tokens effective even when I can do this?

Tags: csrf

I've been playing around with chrome's console.

I found that I can access the textual version of my source code through:

```
document.scripts[2].outerText
```

(the number "2" depends on where the main source code is)

after that, all I had to do was:

```
temp = document.scripts[2].outerText;
temp.indexOf("csrf_token")
```

and couple of other things to get the csrf_token

Does this mean if I can do xss (or run custom JS on the website), then csrf token can fail?

Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this mean if I can do xss (or run custom JS on the website), then csrf token can fail?

Yes. If there is a security hole that lets an attacker perform XSS, then CSRF protection can be circumvented (as can many other things).

The trick is to defend against all kinds of attacks. :)